# Seed MongoDB Data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, seeding

The function below adds data to the database, to the `Food` collection, only if the collection foods is equal to zero. The idea is to be able to only seed the database once.

This is working perfectly. However I'm not sure it's best practice.

My question: What if at some point I wanted to add more data to the database. I could simply change the if statement to make it loop back through the data, but is this the correct way to handle this?

```
function seedfoods() { 
//add the foods to the database

Food.count([], function (err, count) {
console.log(count)

if (count === 0){    

data.forEach(function(seedfoods){
Food.create(seedfoods, function(err, Food){
if(err){
console.log(err)
}
});
});
}
});
}
```

This is what the data looks like:

```
var data = [


{ 
name: "Avocados",
easyFood: true,
phase1: true,
about: "Yum Avocados",
},

{ 
name: "Milk",
easyFood: true,
phase1: true,
about: "Yum Milk",
},

{ 
name: "Apples",
easyFood: true,
phase1: true,
about: "Yum Apples",
},


]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may go for **upsert** function in MongoDB, just find the previously inserted documents from seed data and upsert will insert the new data that does not exist in MongoDB with the seed comparison.

Comment: Thanks! Mind giving an example? :)

Comment: `data.forEach(function(seedfoods){
Food.update({seedfoods}, { upsert: true });
});` here data in **{seedfoods}** do a find logic and as it's given **upsert=true** it inserts new document if the find login not satisfied..
For more queries refer to this link [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/]